# Vue.js: Failed to generate render function

Tags: gulp, vue.js, browserify, jsx

I try to run a simple Vue.js, but I constantly receive the following error:

> [Vue warn]: It seems you are using the standalone build of Vue.js in
>   an environment with Content Security Policy that prohibits
>   unsafe-eval. The template compiler cannot work in this environment.
>   Consider relaxing the policy to allow unsafe-eval or pre-compiling
>   your templates into render functions.
>
> main.js:3180 [Vue warn]: Failed to generate render function:
>   EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because
>   'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'".  in
>
> with(this){return _c('div',{attrs:{"id":"app"}})}
>
> (found in )

Yet, I can't understand what is causing this error. I don't seem to use any dynamic templates and everything should be pre-compiled. Here is the code of my application:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

const Home = Vue.component('home-component', {
  render() {
    return <div>
      <router-link to="/users">Users</router-link>
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    </div>
  }
})

const Users = Vue.component('users-component', {
  render() {
    return <p>Users</p>
  }
})

const NotFound = Vue.component('not-found-component', {
  render() {
    return <p>Not Found</p>
  }
})

const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: Home },
  { path: '/users', component: Users }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

And here is how I process JavaScript files in my gulpfile:

```
const paths = {
  main: 'web/javascript/src/main.js',
  allJs: 'web/javascript/**/*.{js,vue}',
  resultJs: 'public/assets/javascript/main.js',
};

gulp.task('scripts', function() {

  return browserify(paths.main)
    .transform(babelify, { presets: ['es2015'], plugins: ["transform-runtime"] })
    .transform(vueify)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(paths.resultJs))
}
```

There are seem to be many similar questions on StackOverflow, but none of them helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The broweser is throwing Content Security Policy (CSP) error, to get around this issue you should consider switching to the runtime-only build, which is fully CSP-compliant.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#CSP-environments

Also, You have `return` incorrectly written. It should return jsx in pair of paranthesis `()`. The code below should help

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

const Home = Vue.component('home-component', {
  render(h) {
    return(
    <div>
      <router-link to="/users">Users</router-link>
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    </div>
    )
  }
})

const Users = Vue.component('users-component', {
  render(h) {
    return(
      <p>Users</p>
    )
  }
})

const NotFound = Vue.component('not-found-component', {
  render(h) {
    return(
      <p>Not Found</p>
    )
  }
})

const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: Home },
  { path: '/users', component: Users }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: I've added parenthesis, as you suggested, but it didn't help. I still see the same error.